# WampServer : Access to a directory with VPN

Tags: apache, wamp, wampserver, httpd.conf, vhosts

When I go to `http://localhost` I can see the Wamp first page;
but when I enable my VPN and go to `http://localhost/seo.page/` I got this error:
[image: Wamp Error]

I also must mention that `http://localhost` is accessible with enabled VPN;

This is **httpd-vhost.conf** :

```
# Virtual Hosts
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  ServerAlias localhost
  DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
  <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName seo.page
    DocumentRoot "d:/wamp64/www/seopage"
    <Directory  "d:/wamp64/www/seopage/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

When I change Require local to Require all granted doesn't work;
How can I solve it?

Comment: You have a Virtual Host called `seo.page` so you would normally do `http://seo.page`

Comment: Did you add `seo.page` to your `HOSTS` file? Show us your `HOSTS` file please

Comment: Thank you @RiggsFolly . When I go to `http://seo.page` works normally and correct; BUT when I enable my VPN I got the error page; (When I add `seo.page` to apache virtual host wamp adds it automatically into `HOSTS` file.

Comment: Hmm I guess the VPN has no idea how to find that domain as it does not exists in any DNS other than your local DNS Cache

Comment: Why do you need a VPN afterall this is all local to the PC you are sitting on

Comment: @RiggsFolly I'm testing youtube api for fetching videos; and Youtube is filtered in my country.

Comment: Hmmm I think we now are outside my comfort zone, Dont think I can help anymore

Comment: You may get some help, but I would suggest putting that sort of information into the Question so people see it more easily

Answer (score 0):

Found this page after Googling: "WAMP" "VPN"

After reading answers here, realized I hadn't checked my VPN App's settings.

Opened "Settings", unchecked "Block LAN Traffic" and http://localhost/ now works for me.